# How do I change the background image in Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

These intuitive snippets don't work at all:

```
<div id="box" style="background-image: url(img/heart.jpg); ">

or

<style>
#box
{
    background-image: url("img/heart.jpg");
}
```

How do you change the background image?

Comment: try running this file into browser and check if background image appear or not, may be the problem of your image path or style declaration mistakes.

Comment: Are you using cordova command line or phonegap build to create an apk ?